# Postback alternative with 2 dependent dropdown list in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have 2 dependent drop down lists in an aspx web form, the first drop down gets the printer brand name from a database and the second one gets the model based on the brand selected in the first drop down list.

The code linked below is working but it uses postback and it is a problem for me since I'm working with tabs, it keeps getting back to first tab after each postback.

I was wondering if there is an alternative for post back in my case.

Thank you

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PrintXConnectionString_youssef %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Brand]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PrintXConnectionString_youssef %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Distinct P.p_model FROM [Printer] AS P JOIN [Brand] AS B ON P.b_code=B.b_code WHERE (B.b_name = @b_name )">
       <SelectParameters>
           <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="b_name" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
       </SelectParameters>
       </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <label class="control-label col-sm-8">Printer brand:</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="b_name" DataValueField="b_name">
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <label class="control-label col-sm-8">Model reference:</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="p_model" DataValueField="p_model">
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

SOLVED: I added a script manager and an AJAX update panel control from the toolbox in Visual Studio. Here's the code:

```
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-8">Printer Brand:</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="b_name" DataValueField="b_name">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="printerpanel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-8">Model reference:</label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="p_model" DataValueField="p_model">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You could wrap drop downs in an update panel. Or consider client-side solution with ajax request to get data for second drop down. Ajax Control library has a cascading dropdown, for one.

Comment: it worked !!! thanks a lot :)

Comment: You may want to consider posting an answer here to highlight solution you ended up with. That way if anyone else finds this post, it may be useful to them

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Andrei :)